# NoMethodError in Topics#new (undefined method `content' for nil:NilClass) for Rails 3 from netnuts tutorial. 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forum, messageboard

I have been following this tutorial over at net.tutsplus [Forum tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/building-a-forum-from-scratch-with-ruby-on-rails/) but I have run into some issues. The comments have all turned to Spam and the article has been forgotten.

I have followed the tutorial and on posting a new topic i get the following:

```
NoMethodError in Topics#new

Showing /var/www/app/views/topics/_form.html.erb where line #9 raised:

undefined method `content' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #9):

6:     <%= f.text_field :name %>  
7:   </p>  
8:   <p>  
9:     <textarea name="post[content]" cols="80" rows="20"><%= @post.content %></textarea>  
10:   </p>  
11:   <p><%= f.submit "Create" %></p>  
12: <% end %>  

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/topics/new.html.erb
```

My models/controllers and views have been created as instructed by the tutorial.

Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

**Explicitly from the error report:** `@post` is nil and therefore you cannot call `.content` on it.

Since you are calling a *new* action, you probably are just missing `@post = Post.new` in the controller.

I am unfamiliar with the tutorial, but I would suggest refactoring field *line 9* with something more like *line 6*, which uses the rails form helper methods. *i.e.*

```
<%= f.text_area :content, :cols => 80, :rows => 20 %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your post object is uninitalized, you must do

```
@post = Post.new
```

before.